# How to show insert data in the next page

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have two form. In the second page mobile no is not showing.

`echo $_r['mobile'];` in the second form is showing nothing.

I add every page :

```
<?php session_start();?>
<?php include('include/config.php');?>
```

1st form / page: sign.php

```
<form class="ff" action="signc.php" method="POST">
<a>Enter Your Mobile No.</a>
<input type="text" id="inp" name="mobile" required>
</br></br>
<input type="submit" id="btn" value="continue">
</form>
```

signc.php

```
$sql = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `mobile_message`  SET `mobile` = '$mobile'");

 if($sql){

        $cid=$sql['mobile'];

        $_SESSION['cid']=$cid;

    $_SESSION['s']= "OTP sent to your mobile.";
        header('Location:sign2.php');

} else{
    $_SESSION['e']=  "Could not able to execute. ";
    header('Location:sign.php');

}
```

2nd form / page: sign2.php

```
<form class="ff" action="sign2c.php" method="POST">
<a class="ase" >Enter Your Mobile No.</a>
<?php
    $cid=$_SESSION['cid'];
    $_q=mysqli_query($connection, "select * from mobile_message where mobile='$cid'");
    $_r=mysqli_fetch_array($_q);
    echo $_r['mobile'];
    ?>
</br></br>
<a class="ase" >Enter Password</a>
<input type="text" id="inp" name="otp" required>
</br>
<input type="submit" id="btn" value="continue">
</form>
```

Comment: try to "echo $cid" with the query. does it work ?

Comment: I tried "echo $cid"  but no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line `$cid=$_POST['mobile'];`   instead   `$cid=$sql['mobile'];` in `signc.php`

```
$sql = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `mobile_message`  SET `mobile` = '$mobile'");

 if($sql){

        $cid=$_POST['mobile'];   # write instead  $cid=$sql['mobile'];

        $_SESSION['cid']=$cid;

    $_SESSION['s']= "OTP sent to your mobile.";
        header('Location:sign2.php');

} else{
    $_SESSION['e']=  "Could not able to execute. ";
    header('Location:sign.php');

}
```